# mongodb $lookup with foreignfield _id

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, lookup

I want to fetch the result using $lookup having local fields as the array of _id as a string. But its not happening. I also tried by using _id.str but still no results.

```
db.posts.aggregate([

{
    $addFields: {
        TagCount: { $size: "$tags" }
    }
},
{
    $lookup:
    {
        from: "tags",
        localField: "tags",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "tagList"
    }
},
]));
```

The schema for Post Collection

```
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 10,
    set: v => v.replace(/\s\s+/gi, ' '),
    get: v => { console.log(v); return v.replace(/\s\s+/gi, ' '); }
  },
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  headerImage: {
    type: String
  },
  tags: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    validate: {
    validator: function (v) {
       return v.length > 0;
    }
  },
  message: 'There must be one tag',
  ref: 'tags'
 }],
  creationDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
 });
```

Here is the tag Schema Collection

```
 const tagSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 3,
    set: value => value.replace(/\s\s+/gi, ' '),
    get: value => value.replace(/\s\s+/gi, ' ')
  },
  description: {
    type: String
  },
  creationDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
 }  
 }, {
 collection: 'tags'
});
```

Also, I tried other StackOverflow questions but I didn't find any solutions.

Comment: Can you share `tags` schema as well?

Comment: @Jason look at this is working [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/U8ysEYlAFqR)

Comment: @turivishal let me check

Comment: Did you intend for the `tags` field in `posts` to be an array of `DBRef`?

Comment: @turivishal It will work if you don't use custom object Id. Try to replace it with an auto-generated object Id. What I did mistake is I have to insert ObjectId() in array instead of just string https://mongoplayground.net/p/bVGZ9dCL4Gi.

Comment: you need to store an objectId instead of string, but you have already specified type `type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` in tags, that will convert to ObjectId automatically, when you save as string.

Answer (score 1):

Including the `ref: 'tags'` in the schema definition for the `tags` array makes mongoose store the values as DBRef, not ObjectID.

This is useful if you intend to use the `populate` function to retrieve the tag documents on the client side.

The field names in an aggregation are `$id`, `$ref`, and `$db`, which are not valid field names when using dotted notation, like you need to do in the aggregation pipeline.

You could convert each object to an array, which would make it look something like `[ {"k":"$id", v:ObjectId("...")}, {"k":"$ref","v":"tags"}, {"k":"$db","v":"dbname"}]`

Then filter for the `$id` key, retain the corresponding value, and use that array as the local field.

```
db.posts.aggregate([
  {$addFields: {
      TagCount: {$size: "$tags"},
      tag_ids: {
        $map: {
          input: "$tags",
          as: "dbref",
          in: {
            $reduce: {
              input: {$objectToArray: "$$dbref"},
              initialValue: [],
              in: {
                $cond: {
                  if: {$eq: ["$$this.k",{$literal: "$id"}]},
                  then: "$$this.v",
                  else: "$$value"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
  }},
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "tags",
      as: "tag_list",
      localField: "tag_ids",
      foreignField: "_id"
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: I alreay have `ref tags` in tags array. When I run the query, it generates an error.

Comment: I found a solution from your example by converting each id to objectId using $map and $convert.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.posts.aggregate([
{
   $lookup: { 
   from: "tags",
   let: { pid: "$tags" },
   pipeline: [
      {
         $match: {
            $expr: {
                $eq: ["$_id", { $toObjectId: "$$pid" }]
            }
         }
      }
   ],
   as: "tagList"
}]);
```